# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception in TicTacToe game

Tags: java, swt, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting an error that I don't realy understand why. It is a tictactoe game(n x n)
here is the table class

```
public class Table {

private int columns;
private int rows;
private int wincells;
private PieceType[][] table;

public Table() {
}

public Table(int rows, int columns, int wins) {
    this.columns = columns;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.wincells = wins;
    table = new PieceType[rows][columns];
    fillEmpty();
}
public void fillEmpty() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            table[i][j] = PieceType.None;
        }
    }
}

public PieceType getElement(int i, int j) {
    return table[i][j];
}
```

its the getElement() method giving the error after i call the function with
 game.move(e.x, e.y);

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        Button button = (Button) e.getSource();
        MoveResult moveResult = game.move(e.x, e.y);
        if (game.getCurrentPlayer().getPieceType() == PieceType.Cross)
            button.setText("x");
        else
            button.setText("0");
        switch (moveResult) {
        case ValidMove: {
            buttonTable[gridData.horizontalIndent][gridData.verticalIndent]
                    .setText("X");
            game.changePlayer();
        }
        case WinMatch:
            disableButtons();

        case Draw:
            disableButtons();
        }
```

this is where the x and Y get the value

```
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {

            gridData.heightHint = 45;
            gridData.widthHint = 45;

            Button button = new Button(buttonpanel, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setLayoutData(gridData);
            button.setData(new Cell(i,j));
            buttonTable[i][j] = button;
            buttonTable[i][j]
                    .addSelectionListener(new buttSelectionListener());
```

any ideas on what the problem can be? is it from the  game.move(e.x, e.y)? Am I not calling it properly?

StackTrace?:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at backview.Table.getElement(Table.java:42)
at backview.Game.move(Game.java:56)
at frontview.MainGui$buttSelectionListener.widgetSelected(MainGui.java:159)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at frontview.MainGui.<init>(MainGui.java:55)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

here is the method calling

```
if(table.getElement(x, y) != PieceType.None) return MoveResult.InvalidMove;
```

Comment: Where/How are you calling the `getElement` method?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. It shows exactly in which line the problem occurred. Also, using the default constructor can cause problems as your fields would not be initialized. It would be a good idea to provide default values or not to provide the default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to get the `Cell` from the `Button` data and use the `i,j` coordinates to call `getElement()`.

Note: A couple of comments on your `Table` class. The default constructor doesn't make sense if you already know the initial size of the table. If that is the case, make `columns`, `rows` and `wincells` `final` so they cannot be modified during the game. Also, check that the coordinates provided in `getElement()` are within the array bounds:

```
public PieceType getElement(int i, int j) {
    if ((i < 0) || (i >= rows) ||
        (j < 0) || (j >= columns)) {
        return null;
    }

    return table[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `e.x` and `e.y` of the `SelectionEvent` `e` are the coordinate of the click of the mouse, and not the grid. You should get the `Cell` from the `Button` data, and then use it for your game move.
You can fix your `widgetSelected` method like that:

```
Cell c = (Cell) button.getData();
// Then use i and j of the cell for the game move
game.move(c.i, c.j); // or something similar
```

Comment: i tried your way and probably something worked since now i get the same exception but number 2 at the same method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe_Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[][] board = new char[3][3];

        boolean Gameover;
        Gameover = CalculateWinner(board);
        while(!Gameover){

        displayBoard(board);
        System.out.println("Enter row and column for player X");
        int rowX, columnX;
        rowX=Myinput.nextInt();
        columnX= Myinput.nextInt();
        boolean successX = setMove(rowX , columnX ,board,'X');
        while(!successX){
            System.out.println("INVALID MOVE FOR PLAYER X");
            System.out.println("Re-Enter row and column for player X");
            rowX=Myinput.nextInt();
            columnX= Myinput.nextInt();
            successX = setMove(rowX , columnX ,board,'X');
        }
        Gameover= CalculateWinner(board);

        displayBoard(board);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter row and column for player O");
        int rowO, columnO;
        rowO=Myinput.nextInt();
        columnO= Myinput.nextInt();
        boolean successO= setMove(rowO , columnO ,board,'O');
        while(!successO){
            System.out.println("invalid Move");
            System.out.println("Re-Enter row and column for player O");
            rowO=Myinput.nextInt();
            columnO= Myinput.nextInt();
            successO = setMove(rowO , columnO ,board,'0');
        }
        Gameover=CalculateWinner(board);
        }
    }
    public static boolean setMove(int row, int column,char[][] board,char player){
        if(board[row][column]== 'X' || board[row][column]== 'O' ){
            return false;
            }
            else if (player =='X'){
            board[row][column] = 'X';
            return true;
            }
            else{
            board[row][column] = 'O';
    return true;
            }
    }
    public static void displayBoard(char[][]board){
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("|"+board[0][0]+"|"+board[0][1]+"|"+board[0][2]+"|");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("|"+board[1][0]+"|"+board[1][1]+"|"+board[1][2]+"|");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("|"+board[2][0]+"|"+board[2][1]+"|"+board[2][2]+"|");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }
    public static boolean CalculateWinner(char[][] board){
        boolean filled =false;
        for(int column=0; column<=2; column++){
            for(int row =0; row<=2; row++){
                if (board[column][row]!='X'&& board[column][row]!='O'){
                    filled = false;

                }
                else
                { filled = true;
            }
        }
    }
        if (filled){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
}
}
```